# IIS show page not avilaible in Firefox but work fine in other browser?

Tags: html, firefox, iis, iis-8

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRy2h.png

I use IIS installed on my computer and I use it as a server.you can see that page is avilable in Net and work fine in other browser but it's not worked in Firefox. I have tried in Firefox  and latest nightly but it's not worked.

1. I go to private mode and open the site and it's show but in both mode if i press few refresh it's file not found problem.

same thing work fine in other browser. Do someone know what happen.

in net panel I can see 304 but page not worked for me.

Do someone know what happen in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check the proxy settings in Firefox.

Tools > Options > Network > Connection > Settings (make sure 'no proxy' is checked)